# Improve Performance of Oracle SQL Queries from Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm using the JayDeBeAPI python module to connect to a remote machine and query a database:

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@host:port:db')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from table")

data = cur.fetchmany(size=500)
```

This takes 2.15 seconds to return 500 records, and 1.51 minutes to return 25,000 records (I get similar results with a loop `for item in cur.fetchmany(size=500):`). If I need to query 5 million records, this becomes very time consuming.

Alternatively, if I query all 5 million records directly from sql plus on the server, export the result to a csv, scp the file to the local machine, then iterate through the csv file in python, I can gather and process all records in under 15 minutes (without optimizations).

What are some best-practices to improve the performance of Oracle sql queries from python? I strongly prefer the python solution, but if it's hours vs minutes then this is not going to work.

Comment: do you have any indexes on your sql tables?

Comment: have you tried the cx_oracle-package?

Comment: When you directly write to a csv in SQL*Plus you're not querying the data in 500 record chunks... if you were to just get the entire lot in Python would it take 15 minutes?

Comment: How many fields are there in the records being returned, and how big are they? In other words, roughly, how much data is being pushed over the network to get it to the machine it's being processed on? Network latency is your biggest enemy in a situation like this - do you need ALL the fields (`select * from table`)?

Comment: yes, the tables are indexed. also, i have not tried cx_oracle. I will try that as soon as I can get the client installed on my local machine. when i attempt to set fetchmany(size) to something much higher, say 500,000, i get a java heap size memory error.

Comment: @BobJarvis this particular table has 150 columns. i could probably cut the number of columns by 1/3, but I do need most of them. I tested with 10 columns, and i was able to run 4000 records in 2.76 seconds. So that helps.

Comment: Has anyone iterated over millions of rows? If so, what kind of performance have you had with it?

Comment: OK - so at an incredibly rough guess of 10 bytes/field we're looking at 1500 bytes/row. Times 5 million and you're looking at pushing 7.5 gigabytes of data down the pipe. That's something like 60 gigabits, give or take. Let's guess that you've got a 1 Gb network card, which in "the real world" might push 40% of that sustained, so 400Mb/sec - so 60 Gb will take, what, 150 seconds? Thus, using totally flawed and made-up numbers it looks like the network may not be the issue. But I wouldn't trust these numbers... :-)